# how to project array element in document at specific position

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this.

{    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cc08a568f4cdf7870b3a7"),

"phone" : {
        "cell" : [ 
            "854-6574-545", 
            "545-6456-545"
        ],
        "home" : [ 
            "5474-647-574", 
            "455-6878-758"
        ]
    }
}

I want to display output like this.
output

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cc08a568f4cdf7870b3a7"),
        "phone" : {
                "cell" : [
                        "854-6574-545"
                         ]
        }
}
```

please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to project number from array.

**Query:**

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "phone.cell": {
    $slice: 1
  },
  "phone.home": 0
})
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5c6cc08a568f4cdf7870b3a7"),
    "phone": {
      "cell": [
        "854-6574-545"
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Query 2:**

```
db.collection.find({},
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "phone.cell": {
        $slice: 1
      },
      "phone.home": 0
    })
```

**Result 2:**
{

```
    "phone": {
      "cell": [
        "854-6574-545"
      ]
    }
  }
```

** Final Query - using aggregate**

```
db.collections.aggregate([{'$match':{'phone.cell':{'$exists':true}}},
{'$project':{'_id':1,'phone.cell':{$slice:['$phone.cell',1,1]}}}])
```

** Output **

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cc08a568f4cdf7870b3a7"),
    "phone" : {
        "cell" : [ 
            "545-6456-545"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}  This is the error i am getting. we cannot include both include and exclude for same output field.

Comment: are you using mongo shell? if yes, what's the version? specify if other. I've tested this with mongo shell version 4.0.4

Comment: can you post the query that you're running?

Comment: succes query
db.loandetails.find({},{'_id':0,'phone.cell':{$slice:1},
"phone.home":0}).pretty()

error query
db.loandetails.find({},{'_id':1,'phone.cell':{$slice:1},
"phone.home":0}).pretty()

also if the collection has other fields which also gets displayed even though i dont specify in project

Comment: _id will be returned by default. No need to pass it explicitly

Comment: ok but, why are other fields getting displayed ? my output should be just the phone -> cell -> first element.

Comment: pass _id:0 if the _id does not need to be added result